# Configuring spring cache caffeine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to configure Caffeine in my spring project. From reading the [guide,](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html) I can see that there are multiple ways of configuring it into your app ranging from creating cache manager beans to explicitly writing the config in the application.yml properties file.

I have so far used the `application.yml` method of configuring my caffeine cache:

```
spring:
  cache:
    type: Caffeine
    cache-names: test1
    caffeine:
      spec: maximumSize=500, expireAfterAccess=30s
```

And I am using the `@Cachable` annotation in a controller method I have:

```
   @GetMapping
  @Cacheable(value = "test1", key = "#accountId")
 public DTOStatus getStatus(@PathVariable String accountId) {

  if (statusChecker.equals(Check.REQUIRED)) {

     deleteAccountFromCache(accountId);

     return transformDTO(statusChecker);

  } else {
     return transformDTO(statusChecker);
  }
}

  @CacheEvict(value = "test1", key = "#accountId")
  public void deleteAccountFromCache(String accountId){
  //Method body left blank. The annotation deletes the accountId from the cache.
  }
```

I want to know if I've configured the cache properly. I can't test it at the moment but just want to be sure that I've done all the necessary steps in enabling caffeine

Comment: Did this worked well?

Answer (score 0):

Also add org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching annotation in your configuration java class, for example.

```
@EnableCaching
class ApplicationConfig {
```

Comment: I'm using application.yml as my config so I dont think i can add annotations to a .yml file